# how to get each element in one record from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get each element in one record 'Pests' in database 'crop'.Actually my purpose is to get all the distinct pests in 'Pests' field.

BUT There are not only one element in 'Pests' in database. For example:

```
Name                                Pests
```

---

```
Name1                              Grasshopper    
                                   Thrips    
                                   Potato Leafhoppe    
                                   Stink Bugs    
                                     ... ...

Name2                              Green Cloverworm
                                   Mexican Bean Bettle
                                   ... ...
```

My code is like the following. But the result is not what I want. This will display all the pest in each column. But I want all the distinct pests in all column and display each pest in a table, like

```
Pest | Grasshopper|Thrips|Potato Leafhoppe|Stink Bugs|Green Cloverworm|Mexican Bean Bettle|... ...
```

Im so appreciate if anyone could give me some hint for how to achieve this. 
Thanks so much!

```
$search = "SELECT distinct Pests from crop ORDER BY Pests ASC";
$result = mysql_query($search);

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
       echo '<td>'.$rs[0].'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: You need to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF) your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you shouldn't be storing multiple values in one row cell. SQL operations cant work on data like this.

You need to store your data like so.

```
Name     Pest

Name1    Grasshopper    
Name1    Thrips    
Name1    Potato Leafhoppe    
Name1    Stink Bugs    
Name2    Green Cloverworm
Name2    Mexican Bean Bettle
```